# Python3 pickle: AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'CHJ_tiny_obj'

Tags: python, pickle

When I tried to restore a `.pkl` model with python3 `pickle`:

```py
>>> import pickle
>>> with open('./019-SUV.pkl', 'rb') as file:
...     pickle.load(file, encoding='latin1')
```

it raised an error:

```py
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'CHJ_tiny_obj' on <module 'objloader' from  
'/home/xx/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/objloader/__init__.py'>
```

Comment: This is going to heavily depend on how the pickle was created in the first place. Can you post the pickled object's `__getstate__` method if it has one, or it's `__dict__` attribute otherwise? Have you made sure that your unpickling program can import the modules required for the pickled object to exist?

Comment: I guess this problem is caused by the pkl file is created by python 2 pickle. You can try converting the pkl file to python 3 compatible format.

Comment: I guess this might happened because of missing dependencies. Did you import module `objloader` and are you sure there is `CHJ_tiny_obj` definition inside? If you have different versions of the package then `pickle` does not know the definition of the object and raises `AttributeError`. [This post](https://www.stefaanlippens.net/python-pickling-and-dealing-with-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-thing.html) can be also useful.